# Using ColorBox inside a GridView in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, colorbox

I am using [ColorBox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox) library for a link inside a `GridView` row, but the `colorbox` don't show the popup window, but it redirect to the page.. If I took the same link to outside ,, it opens the `colobox` window .. why ?

The link to open the colorbox window :

```
<a id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_gvFSuper_ctl07_HyperLink1" href="AddStaff.aspx" class="showColorBox">Test</a>
```

javascript:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        $(".showColorBox").colorbox({ iframe: true, innerWidth: 800, innerHeight: 400 });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Does that link exist in the document at the time you try to assign colorbox to it?  If not, you may have to use event delegation.  For example:

```
$('document').on('click', '.showColorBox', function(e){
    $.colorbox({href: this.href, iframe: true, innerWidth: 800, innerHeight: 400})
    e.preventDefault();
});
```